# Configure apache to load website without www

Tags: apache

I have a domain name mapped on to an ip address on a Linux server, In Apache what is the config that i have to place such that when I type in mywebsite.com i reach the website. Currently I have to type in www.mywebsite.com to get the website. Is there a config, such that when i type in mywebsite.com i reach the website directly.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemail.com
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mywebsite/
    CustomLog /var/www/logs/mywebsite.com.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/error_logs/mywebsite.com.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about setting up web server.

Comment: Please review this discussion http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261726/are-questions-about-webserver-config-files-and-rewrite-rules-on-topic to find better place for your question.

Comment: Sorry for this, But found the answer, I need to use ServerAlias.